# Переопределение FOSUserBundle маршрутов в Symfony2

Tags: symfony2, route, fosuserbundle

Имеется сайт на Symfony2.8, регистрация и все к ней прилагающее выполнено при помощи FOSUserBundle.

Суть вопроса в следующем: не получается выполнить красиво([как здесь, к примеру](https://anil.io/blog/symfony/fosuserbundle/redirect-logged-in-user-from-login-page/) ) редирект в админку после авторизации пользователя с ролью админа.

Стартовая страница доступна только после авторизации, закоменчено "некрасивое исполнение".

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="catalog.books.list", options={"expose": true})
 */
public function listAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if ($user === null) {
        return $this->redirect('/login');
    }
    /*
    $baseUrl = $this->get('request')->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
    $currentUrl = $request->server->get('HTTP_REFERER');
    $lastPath = substr($currentUrl, strpos($currentUrl, $baseUrl));
    $lastPath = str_replace($baseUrl, '', $lastPath);

    // admin redirect to page 'admin.books'
    if($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') && ($lastPath == '/login')) {
        return $this->redirect('admin/books');
    }
    */
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Frontend/Catalog:list.html.twig', [
        'defaultLayout' => $request->cookies->get('visibleLayout')
    ]);
}
```

Файл `security.yml`:

```
security:
encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
            # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /login
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/js/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register/*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/demo, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/getPage, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/getAsset, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/previewPage,  role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/_error/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/view, role: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_DEMO_USER ] }
    - { path: ^/notes/*, role: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_DEMO_USER ] }
    - { path: ^/bookmarks/*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/search, role: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_DEMO_USER ] }
    - { path: ^/*, allow_if: "not has_role('ROLE_DEMO_USER')" }

access_denied_url: /login
```

Настройки типа `always_use_default_target_path: false` и `default_target_path:/` не увенчались успехом.

Расширение FOS-овского контроллера:

```
class SecurityController extends FOSSecurityController{
public function loginAction(Request $request){
    $auth_checker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');
    $router = $this->get('router');
    // 307: Internal Redirect
    if ($auth_checker->isGranted(['ROLE_ADMIN'])) {
        // SUPER_ADMIN roles go to the `admin_home` route
        return new RedirectResponse($router->generate('admin.books'), 307);
    }
    if ($auth_checker->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        // Everyone else goes to the `home` route
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }
    // Always call the parent unless you provide the ENTIRE implementation
    return parent::loginAction($request);}}
```

Но, он сюда почти не попадает, после логина редиректится сразу на "/" - home-page так сказать...

Форма логина, для полноты картины:

```html
<form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post" id="login-from">

  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

  <label for="username" class="placeholder username">
    <span>Email address</span>
    <input type="email" id="username"  {# placeholder="Email address" #} name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" tabindex="1" required="required"/>
  </label>

  <label for="password" class="placeholder">
    <span>Password</span>
    <a href="{{ path('fos_user_resetting_request') }}" class="forgot">Forgot?</a>
    <input tabindex="2" type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" />
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" class="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
  <label for="remember_me">Remember me</label>
  <div>
    <input tabindex="3" type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="Log in" />
    <a href="{{ path("fos_user_registration_register") }}" class="submit">Create account</a>
  </div>

</form>
```

Может у кого-то будут идеи по поводу где тут подшаманить нужно?

Comment: В общем, вопрос вроде решился при помощи [LoginHandlers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783381/fosuserbundle-redirect-from-login-page-after-logged-in)

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

Решение - расширения дефолтного `DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler`

Кастомный хендлер `LoginSuccessHandler.php`:

```
namespace  AppBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;

class LoginSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{

    protected $router;
    protected $authorizationChecker;

    public function __construct(Router $router, AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker, HttpUtils $httpUtils, array $options = array())
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;

        parent::__construct($httpUtils, $options);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $response = null;

        if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
        {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('admin.books'));
        }
        else if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_USER'))
        {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('catalog.books.list'));
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Фрагмент `serviсes.yml`

```
authentication.handler.login_success_handler:
    class:  AppBundle\Handler\LoginSuccessHandler
    arguments:  ['@router', '@security.authorization_checker', '@security.http_utils', {}]
```

Фаервол в `security.yml`:

```
 firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                success_handler: authentication.handler.login_success_handler
                # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /login
            anonymous:    true
```

Родительский Хендлер (для общей картины) `DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler.php`

```
namespace Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\ParameterBagUtils;

/**
 * Class with the default authentication success handling logic.
 *
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 * @author Johannes M. Schmitt <schmittjoh@gmail.com>
 * @author Alexander <iam.asm89@gmail.com>
 */
class DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    protected $httpUtils;
    protected $options;
    protected $providerKey;
    protected $defaultOptions = array(
        'always_use_default_target_path' => false,
        'default_target_path' => '/',
        'login_path' => '/login',
        'target_path_parameter' => '_target_path',
        'use_referer' => false,
    );

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param HttpUtils $httpUtils
     * @param array     $options   Options for processing a successful authentication attempt
     */
    public function __construct(HttpUtils $httpUtils, array $options = array())
    {
        $this->httpUtils = $httpUtils;
        $this->setOptions($options);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, $this->determineTargetUrl($request));
    }
//...
}
```